# Actual numbers to the human readable values

Tags: javascript, function, human-readable

I have data in bytes. I need to draw this values as human readable labels on a chart (like 2.5KB, 14MB etc.) and need to help with function (input data - actual value, output - human readable string).

I did funcion like this, but I want more elegant realization

```
function tickFormatter(value, type) {

    var suffix = (type == "bytes") ? ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'] : ['', 'K', 'M', 'G']

    if(value > (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        return (value / (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + suffix[3]
    } else if(value > (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        return (value / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + suffix[2]
    } else if (value > (1024 * 1024)) {
        return (value / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + suffix[1]
    } else {
        return value.toFixed(2) + suffix[0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I love this implementation: clear and compact:

```
function readablizeBytes(bytes) {
    var s = ['bytes', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'];
    var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, e)).toFixed(2) + " " + s[e];
}
```

Usage:

```
readablizeBytes(10000000)
"9.54 MB"
```

I don't take the credit of this.

Comment: *I don't take the credit of this.* Who takes the credit of this?

Comment: what does 'e' represent?

Comment: the unit (kB, MB...) with a maths gimmick ;-)
kB is 2^10 bytes, MB is (2^10)^2 bytes...

Comment: if you change third line to `var e = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(value)) / Math.log(1000));` you'll be able to show negative values.

Comment: Aren't these technically KiB/MiB etc instead of KB/MB etc ?

Comment: The way of Nature: to make, but don't take the credit for it... The best solution so far.

Answer (score 18):

This is what I use. It rounds up to the nearest unit, so 1000 is "0.98KB"
If you don't want that, then change the first Math.round to a floor.

```
var SizePrefixes = ' KMGTPEZYXWVU';
function GetHumanSize(size) {
  if(size <= 0) return '0';
  var t2 = Math.min(Math.round(Math.log(size)/Math.log(1024)), 12);
  return (Math.round(size * 100 / Math.pow(1024, t2)) / 100) +
    SizePrefixes.charAt(t2).replace(' ', '') + 'B';
}
```

Comment: But what is your source on the X, W, V and U suffixes? They are not mentioned on Wikipedia.

Comment: Xona, Weka, Vunda, Uda ... not formal, but you can find it in a bunch of places like: http://jimvb.home.mindspring.com/unitsystem.htm ...Then again, if you are at that scale, you have other problems to think about other then names :)

Comment: `(1 << 30) * 1000` => `'0.98TB'` ...and with `Math.floor()` `(1 << 30) * 1000` => `'1000GB'`. I expect `'1TB'`

Comment: Au contraire, @Amir, at that scale (age of universe, bank balance, lines of code in play), your worst problem may very well be getting these prefixes right.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function readable (nb_bytes) {
    if (nb_bytes < 1024) return nb_bytes + 'B';
    else if (nb_bytes < 1024 * 1024) return (Math.round((nb_bytes / 1024) * 100) / 100) + 'KB';
    else return (Math.round((nb_bytes / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100) + 'MB';
}
```

[EDIT]

Alright, since you want something more elegant, I assume you're thinking of a loop. Maybe this will suit your needs:

```
function readable (nb_bytes,type) {
    var suffix = type ? ['B','KB','MB','GB'] : ['','K','M','G'];
    var i = 0;
    while (nb_bytes > 1024 && i < suffix.length - 1) {
        ++i;
        nb_bytes = Math.round((nb_bytes / 1024) * 100) / 100;
    }
    return (nb_bytes) + suffix[i];
}
```

Here I assumed `type` was a boolean - change to whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of Amer's:

```
(function GetHumanSize(size) {
  var SizePrefixes = ['','K','M','G','T','P','E','Z','Y'];
  if(size <= 0) return '0';
  var t2 = Math.min(Math.round(Math.log(size)/Math.log(1024)),
                    SizePrefixes.length-1);
  return String((Math.round(size * 100 / Math.pow(1024, t2)) / 100)) + 
         ' ' + SizePrefixes[t2] + 'iB';
})(Math.pow(2,131)) === "2251799813685248 YiB"
```

With:

- IEC suffixes
- No non-standard suffixes

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatSize(size, standard) {
    if (standard) { 
        standard = standard.toLowerCase();
    }

    var n = 0, 
        base = standard == 'si' ? 1000 : 1024, 
        prefixes = ' KMGTPEZY';

    if (size < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (size >= base) {
        n = Math.floor( Math.log(size) / Math.log(base) );

        if (n >= prefixes.length) {
            return 'N/A';
        }

        size = ( size / Math.pow(base, n) ).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ';
    }

    return size + prefixes[n] + ( n && standard == 'iec' ? 'i' : '' ) + 'B';
}
```

Test:

```
for (var i = 0; i++ < 10;) console.log( formatSize( Math.pow(10, i) ) );
```

Output:

```
10 B
100 B
1000 B
9.77 KB
97.66 KB
976.56 KB
9.54 MB
95.37 MB
953.67 MB
9.31 GB
```

Hello from 2022:

```
function humanSize(size, iec = true) {
  let base = iec ? 1024 : 1000
  let units = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T']
  let i = Math.log(size) / Math.log(base) | 0
  return `${(size / Math.pow(base, i)).toFixed(2) * 1} ${units[i]}${i && iec ? 'i' : ''}B`
}
undefined
humanSize(2048)
'2 KiB'
humanSize(2000)
'1.95 KiB'
humanSize(500000000000)
'465.66 GiB'
humanSize(500000000000, false)
'500 GB'
```

Answer (score 1):

I took what I felt the best of the top two solutions and came up with this, its faster than the first, slower than the second. But its purpose is to always have exactly 3 characters, and not round. The reason for the 3 character limit was due to size constraints for the container it was being placed into. Additionally should you want to use it to format non base 2 numbers all you need to do is change kilo to 1000. It also short circuits if the number is under 1k

```
var kilo = 1024, suffix = ' KMGTPEZYXWVU', humanReadable = function (number) {
  var retValue = false;
  if (typeof number == "number") {
      if (number < kilo) {
          retValue = number.toString();
      } else {
          var e = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(kilo));
          retValue = Number((number / Math.pow(kilo, e)).toString().slice(0, 3)) + suffix.charAt(e) + 'B';
      }
  }
  return retValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You answers really helped me, so I decided to write an utility method that solves this problem of size formatting once and for all.

Check out my JSUtils repo wiki page: https://bitbucket.org/AAverin/jsutils/ | https://github.com/AAverin/JSUtils
It has **humanReadeableSize** method that uses Amir's way of rounding the size, but also supports conversion between the usual base of 2 (KiB, MiB) and base 10 numbers (KB, MB).

It can round down to the closest value, but also round up in case you want, for example, get how much KB are in PB.

Feel free to grab it and use in your projects!

Answer (score 0):

Could use number_to_human_size(number, options = {})

```
number_to_human_size(1234567)
```

examples:

```
number_to_human_size(123)                                          # => 123 Bytes
number_to_human_size(1234)                                         # => 1.21 KB
number_to_human_size(12345)                                        # => 12.1 KB
number_to_human_size(1234567)                                      # => 1.18 MB
number_to_human_size(1234567890)                                   # => 1.15 GB
number_to_human_size(1234567890123)                                # => 1.12 TB
number_to_human_size(1234567, precision: 2)                        # => 1.2 MB
number_to_human_size(483989, precision: 2)                         # => 470 KB
number_to_human_size(1234567, precision: 2, separator: ',')        # => 1,2 MB
```

as in documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human_size