# How can I format numbers using 1.5K, 1.6M 10B, etc?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Is there a js library that takes a nuber >=1 and formats it using vulgar abreviations like 100k$ or 10M$, etc so its possible to shorten numbers in a way everybody understands?
So basicly:

1=>1
100=>100
1354=>1.3K
1586543=>1.5M
4234567895=>4.2B

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498866/actual-numbers-to-the-human-readable-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need a library to do this? You could just a switch:

```js
const getAbb = (n) => {
  const number = n.toString()
  const len = number.length
  const place = len % 3 || 3
  let abb, r
  switch(true) {
    case len > 9:
      abb = 'B'
      break
    case len > 6:
      abb = 'M'
      break
    case len > 3:
      abb = 'K'
      break
    default:
      return number
  }
  
  return `${number.slice(0, place)}.${number.slice(place, place + 1)}${abb}`
}

console.log(getAbb(1))
console.log(getAbb(12))
console.log(getAbb(123))
console.log(getAbb(1234))
console.log(getAbb(12345))
console.log(getAbb(123456))
console.log(getAbb(1234567))
console.log(getAbb(12345678))
```

Comment: Mostly because I don't like reinventing the wheel, even on small stuff

Comment: this doesnt work with  decimal number